# Intent goes to activity that doesn't exist

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent

I've tried to make datePickerDialog and go there using intent, but instead it goes to the activity I don't have.

My intent method:

```
public void toDate(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DateActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

My DateActivity.java class:

```
public class DateActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener  {

//using the datePickerDialog.

}
```

activity_date.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".DateActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/picDate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Pic Date"
    android:onClick="datePicker"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_below="@+id/picDate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/showDate"
    android:textSize="18dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The thing I have after I press the button is all the same buttons like in activity_main, but has no ListActivity and the fontSize of buttons is the same.

Comment: Did you call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_date);` on `DateActivity` class?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your DateActivity.java class

```
public class DateActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_date);

        //using the datePickerDialog.
    }
}
```